# Font-Face Issue in Firefox

Tags: firefox, font-face

I have an issue with #Fontface via MyFonts for ProximaNova... Only in firefox and for some weights.

As you can see by the screenshot my fonts are not loading in firefox but have no problem in Safari and in Chrome. I've also noticed, on another page where I have multiple weights, some work, others do not. I have no altered the font face css file that was generated for me, other then adding font-weight/style to normal.

```
    @font-face {font-family: 'ProximaNovaS-Extrabld';src: url('../webfonts/278301_2_0.eot');src: url('../webfonts/278301_2_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../webfonts/278301_2_0.woff') format('woff'),url('../webfonts/278301_2_0.ttf') format('truetype'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
    @font-face {font-family: 'ProximaNovaS-Semibold';src: url('../webfonts/278301_6_0.eot');src: url('../webfonts/278301_6_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../webfonts/278301_6_0.woff') format('woff'),url('../webfonts/278301_6_0.ttf') format('truetype'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
    @font-face {font-family: 'ProximaNova-Extrabld';src: url('../webfonts/278301_F_0.eot');src: url('../webfonts/278301_F_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../webfonts/278301_F_0.woff') format('woff'),url('../webfonts/278301_F_0.ttf') format('truetype'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
    @font-face {font-family: 'ProximaNova-Regular';src: url('../webfonts/278301_13_0.eot');src: url('../webfonts/278301_13_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../webfonts/278301_13_0.woff') format('woff'),url('../webfonts/278301_13_0.ttf') format('truetype'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
    @font-face {font-family: 'ProximaNova-Bold';src: url('../webfonts/278301_14_0.eot');src: url('../webfonts/278301_14_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../webfonts/278301_14_0.woff') format('woff'),url('../webfonts/278301_14_0.ttf') format('truetype'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
    @font-face {font-family: 'ProximaNovaS-Bold';src: url('../webfonts/278301_7_0.eot');src: url('../webfonts/278301_7_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../webfonts/278301_7_0.woff') format('woff'),url('../webfonts/278301_7_0.ttf') format('truetype'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
    @font-face {font-family: 'ProximaNova-Semibold';src: url('../webfonts/278301_12_0.eot');src: url('../webfonts/278301_12_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../webfonts/278301_12_0.woff') format('woff'),url('../webfonts/278301_12_0.ttf') format('truetype'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
```

Here is a sample of the bigger text style

```
    h1 { color: #ff6500; display: inline; font-family: 'ProximaNova-Semibold'; font-size: 34pt; letter-spacing: 1px; line-height: 42pt; text-align: left; text-transform: uppercase; }
```

I've tried to do some tests... as far as putting the same markup and style of working weights (in firefox) in the the same page as shown in the screen shot, which then doesn't work. So I'm stumped.

Thank you for your help.

---------- Update -----------

It seems for the most part Firefox is displaying the fonts correctly. However as you can see in the top window (firefox) the text different from the the bottom (Safari) This is really stumping me... http://postimg.org/image/vftkepyw1/

Comment: Before you start digging in I would just do a cache clear in firefox. I had mine remember old fonts when I implemented a new one. 
Ctrl + F5 in windows or full clear here.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache

Comment: Thank you for your input/advice. I had already tried that, no luck. Tried it again just to be sure, unfortunately with the same results.

Comment: Its very hard to diagnose this issue without samples. Try and post a demo on jsfiddle so we can help.

Comment: http://www.chezvalois.com/test/index.html

Comment: Font files do not exist at the specified path.
http://www.chezvalois.com/test/webfonts/278301_13_0.woff

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I must have overlooked my paths when doing my test page... Current some weights are working and others are not. If you look at this screen shot, you will see the top (firefox) text is different from the bottom (safari) This is really stumping me.

http://postimg.org/image/vftkepyw1/

Comment: Proxima Nova is showing fine in firefox all weights. Are you sure its not your browser? Is firefox up to date?

Comment: The links on the site above contain malicious code
Location: tidesoffortune.com/a
Access has been blocked as the threat Mal/HTMLGen-A has been found on this website.

Comment: Ah! That sounds bad... What contains malicious code? The font-face?
Yes, Up to date (24.0)

Answer (score 0):

Font files do not exist at the specified path.
I believe you where just not linking to the specified font.

The above link http://www.chezvalois.com/test/index.html is now showing all proxima nova fonts in my Firefox.

I believe this is now fixed.